# Getting a drive to automount on startup

Tags: partitioning, rhythmbox, music, disk, automount

I've got a drive (well, a separate partition actually) that has my music on it, and in theory I should just be able to hit play in Rhythmbox and it'll work. But for some reason, I need to personally go into the drive and just open the drive before rhythmbox will actually realise the files are still there.

A partial solution seemed to have been to put the following command into the startup applications list:

```
--mount /dev/sdb4
```

But that only worked when I logged in and out to test it. It doesn't actually work when booting up.

EDIT: I've just noticed that the drive is no longer being listed by Ubuntu automatically. I can see it if I look for it under drives, but its not automatically coming up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an entry into /etc/fstab

Im not at my pc else i would tell you the line !

Look at that file, add a new line the same as the line mounting your / partition. Edit the new line to point to your own music partition.

Google fstab, its quite easy to set up and well documented all over the net.

Answer (score 0):

Worked out an alternate way to do what I wanted: just change the default directory for Rhythmbox to search for music. Can't believe I didn't think of this already. Gah!